# Openshift mysql-operator - how to set persistent global parameters

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

This post is to share on how to modify/set certain global (e.g. local_infile = 1) or session parameter to persist between restart, with MySQL-Operator template.

MySQL 8 MySQL-Operator template does not allow us to modify the configs under /etc/my.cnf.d/*. But the developer has been provided an alternate approach, which is to set the configuration under ${APP_DATA}/mysq-cfg/ (APP_DATA = /opt/app-root/src).

Steps:

1. Create a configMap.
2. Mount the configMap under ${APP_DATA}/mysq-cfg.
3. Start the Pod.

In OpenShift 4.x,  ConfigMap can be added from UI and in OpenShift 3.x use oc CLI command.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: 50-my-tuning-cnf
  namespace: rstudio-connnect-db
data:
  50-my-tuning.cnf: |-
    [mysqld]
    key_buffer_size = ${MYSQL_KEY_BUFFER_SIZE}
    max_allowed_packet = ${MYSQL_MAX_ALLOWED_PACKET}
    table_open_cache = ${MYSQL_TABLE_OPEN_CACHE}
    sort_buffer_size = ${MYSQL_SORT_BUFFER_SIZE}
    read_buffer_size = ${MYSQL_READ_BUFFER_SIZE}
    read_rnd_buffer_size = 256K
    net_buffer_length = 2K
    thread_stack = 256K
    myisam_sort_buffer_size = 2M
    local_infile = 1
```

The DeploymentConfig should be updated with volumes and volumeMounts

volumes:

```
- name: 50-my-tuning-cnf-vol
  configMap:
    name: 50-my-tuning-cnf
    items:
      - key: 50-my-tuning.cnf
        path: 50-my-tuning.cnf
    defaultMode: 420
```

And

volumeMounts:

```
        volumeMounts:
        - name: 50-my-tuning-cnf-vol
          mountPath: /opt/app-root/src/mysql-cfg/
```

The pre-init scripts of MySQL operator will over-write the default with custom settings from ${APP_DATA}/mysql-cfg/*.

Note: It looks like the pre-init scripts only recognize the filename 20-default-authentication-plugin.cnf, 40-paas.cnf,  50-my-tuning.cnf or base.cnf.

Comment: what's the question?

Comment: Is this approach correct or is there a better way to solve this?